# Can Visual Studio print a colorized C++ file from the command line?

Tags: command-line, pdf, printing, visual-studio-2010

I teach and I often have a large number of C++ source files from students that I'd like to pretty-print for grading as PDFs using Visual Studio's formatting and syntax coloring.   I know how to do this manually, tediously clicking through the menus, one file at a time.  I'd like do it from a script, but it doesn't appear that VS supports any command line options or other means to support this.

My question is, have I overlooked something?   Is there a way to get VS to pretty-print from a script?